# UIPIckerView showing strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm new to iOS development and I have an assignment where I need to implement a a UITextfield which upon a tap, brings a country selector UIPickerView.

I went through some online tutorials and got it working somehow. But it shows some strange behaviour which I can't seem to figure out.

Some strange black bars are appearing, with the picker content visibly duplicated each time I scroll.

I believe I've made a mistake in my code, forgive my lack of knowledge but can't seem to figure out what is wrong in the code.

Could you please tell me what has gone wrong?

[image]

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if ([textField isEqual:self.countryTextField]) {
        countryPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        countryPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        self.countryPicker.delegate = self;
        self.countryPicker.dataSource = self;
       // [self.countryPicker reloadAllComponents];
       countryPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
   //     [countryPicker init:self];

        textField.inputView = countryPicker;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (UIView * ) pickerView: (UIPickerView * ) pickerView viewForRow: (NSInteger) row forComponent: (NSInteger) component reusingView: (UIView * ) view {


        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    label.text =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.countries objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"name"]];


    [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];

        return label;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong in your code, even though it should not behave like that. Is the issue reproducible? or happened only once.

Comment: It looks like a new `UIPickerView` is getting created and added to the screen each time text field begins editing without removing old `UIPickerView` from the screen.

Comment: yes you initilize the pickerview in viewdidload method and set hidden property as per reqirement

Comment: I did try to initialise the pickerview in viewdidload and used its hidden property, but still the error is there. Anymore ideas? Also, Why is it that the content doesn't appear correctly on Picker? @kamalesh-kumar-yadav

Comment: Have you implemented these methods: `-pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:`
`-numberOfComponentsInPickerView:`
`-pickerView:widthForComponent:`

Comment: Also, for a plain vanilla text label, no need to implement `-pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`.  You can just implement `-pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` and return a string.

Comment: Hi @JonBrooks, Yes I did implement pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent earlier, but then the pickerView appears empty, even though when I scroll there appears to be data in it and the UITextField is filled with the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found the issue. It was a silly mistake of defining a wrong number of components in numberOfComponentsInPickerView

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are few things need to be changed in your code
1.Don't allocate memory to UIPickerView every time your text field get edited -textFieldShouldBeginEditing

```
if(self.countryPicker == nil)
{
   self.countryPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   self.countryPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.countryPicker.delegate = self;
    self.countryPicker.dataSource = self;
   self.countryPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
}
```

2.Either use self.countrypicker -> class property or countrypicker don't use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Might be initialising every time , instead of initialising at every time , Check whether the `UIPicker` is already initialised

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if ([textField isEqual:self.countryTextField]) {

       if(! countryPicker){
        countryPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        countryPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        self.countryPicker.delegate = self;
        self.countryPicker.dataSource = self;
        countryPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
       }
        textField.inputView = countryPicker;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said,but the problem is still there. I've checked my code for multiple initialisations of UIPicker but there isn't any.